# How to pass Boundfield value to templatefield within gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have task to develop on project. In that I have one price table with some items.

My table will look like this.

```
ID     Item    Price   Date
--     ----    -----  -----
1       a       3       1/1/2013
2       b       4       2/3/2013
3       c       7       3/3/2013
```

now I have to  edit price value from asp.net gridview.

my client requirement is, when they start editing price value, they want to know existing price value with modified date.

**for example If user going to modify value to item 'a'**

my new table show like this.

```
id   item   price   date      exist1   exist2  exist3 exist4
--   ----   -----   ----      -----    -----   ------ ------
1    a      6      2/3/2012     3       7      9       9
```

so, now we need have gridview like this.

```
id   item    price   date     exist1   exist2   exist3   exist4
1     a       3     2/3/2013
```

in this gridview **how to pass my price column  value '3' to exist1 column**

.when there is any modification in price column, that current price value have to shift automatically to `exist1,exist2,exits3,exist4.`

```
<asp:TemplateField >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Eval='< Price> Text="Exist1"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField >
```

how to achieve this..?

Comment: Could you show the code you've written so far, and what's not working for you?  Generally, Stack Overflow is not for writing complete applications / features for you.  It sounds like you know what you want.  Give it a shot.

Comment: just I need a idea to solve this issue. I just want know, is there any chance to do by using "OnRowEditing" Property.?

Comment: <asp:ItemTemplate HeaderText="Exist1"> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></TextBox>                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="price" Eval="price">                    here how to pass boundfield value to TextBox1?